# rvest not suitable for this scraping functionality

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

I am trying to use R to webscrape this webpage for its title contents, but `rvest` isnt turning out to be a good tool for this job.

**My code:**

```
url <-"https://letterboxd.com/crew/list/most-fans-on-letterboxd-with-pronoun-she/"

title <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes("span .frame-title") %>% # selector 
  html_text()
```

Which should give me the title associated with the given node (using example: the film ***Her (2013)***)...

```
<span class="frame-title" data-reactid=".c.3.1">Her (2013)</span>
```

...but instead I get blank ("") output each time and for each slot.

I was considering the `RCurl` package  something but I dont know if it really would help with my situation in extracting nodes. I'd like some assistance in this department for grabbing the titles under "frame-title" for this webpage. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page source for that website does not looks like what you have posted. The below should fix it:

```
read_html(url) %>% 
    html_nodes("img") %>% 
    html_attr("alt")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I came to the same conclusion shortly after posting the question, but I was still curious about what others might say because at first I didnt check the page source. Where I found the nodes we from using the `inspect element` feature on Chrome on one of the film titles and was able to find this particular node of the site embedded in the html skeleton. If I face a similar problem, what if I cannot find what Im looking for in the similar way this solution was found? I dont know how advanced web scraping can get on R, so I wondered.

Comment: you can save down the downloaded url in a html file to take a look. in the end, its downloading the webpage and parsing it for info.